# Draw a circle with google maps api3 that doesn't resize

Tags: google-maps-api-3

With google maps api2 I was drawing a circle using this code:

```
var markerPoint = currentMarker.getPoint();

var polyPoints = Array();

var mapNormalProj = G_NORMAL_MAP.getProjection();
var mapZoom = map.getZoom();
var clickedPixel = mapNormalProj.fromLatLngToPixel(markerPoint, mapZoom);

var polySmallRadius = 20;

var polyNumSides = 20;
var polySideLength = 18;

for (var a = 0; a<(polyNumSides+1); a++) {
 var aRad = polySideLength*a*(Math.PI/180);
 var polyRadius = polySmallRadius; 
 var pixelX = clickedPixel.x + 5 + polyRadius * Math.cos(aRad);
 var pixelY = clickedPixel.y - 10 + polyRadius * Math.sin(aRad);
 var polyPixel = new GPoint(pixelX,pixelY);
 var polyPoint = mapNormalProj.fromPixelToLatLng(polyPixel,mapZoom);
 polyPoints.push(polyPoint);
}
// Using GPolygon(points,  strokeColor?,  strokeWeight?,  strokeOpacity?,  fillColor?,  fillOpacity?)
highlightCircle = new GPolygon(polyPoints,"#000000",2,0.0,"#FF0000",.5);
map.addOverlay(highlightCircle);
```

I've managed to transform this code to api3:

```
var markerPoint = currentMarker.getPosition();

var polyPoints = Array();


var mapNormalProj = map.getProjection();
var mapZoom = map.getZoom();
var clickedPixel = mapNormalProj.fromLatLngToPoint(markerPoint);

var polyRadius = 20;

var polyNumSides = 20;
var polySideLength = 18;

for (var a = 0; a<(polyNumSides+1); a++) {
 var aRad = polySideLength*a*(Math.PI/180);
 var pixelX = clickedPixel.x + 5 + (polyRadius * Math.cos(aRad));
 var pixelY = clickedPixel.y - 10 + (polyRadius * Math.sin(aRad));
 var polyPixel = new google.maps.Point(pixelX,pixelY);
 var polyPoint = mapNormalProj.fromPointToLatLng(polyPixel);
 polyPoints.push(polyPoint);
}

highlightCircle = new google.maps.Polygon({
 paths: polyPoints,
 strokeColor: "#FF0000",
 strokeOpacity: 0.8,
 strokeWeight: 2,
 fillColor: "#FF0000",
 fillOpacity: 0.35
});

highlightCircle.setMap(map);
```

If you look more closely at the api3 example, the mapZoom variable is not used anywhere.

In api2, the code generates a small circle around my marker - around 35px radius. When I zoom into the map, the radius stays at 35px (because the zoom is taken into account).

With api3 on the other hand, I have a huge circle - more than 200px wide and when I zoom in, the circle becomes bigger and bigger.

It behaves the same way as the circle object available in api3.

What I want is just a small circle around my marker, that is not 100km in diameter, but just a few pixels around my marker (this circle acts like a hover element in html).

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using custom marker, not a circle. See "Vector Icon" from the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 10
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the calculation based on the Point plane which plane remains the same no matter what zoom level you are at. You probably mean to do the calculation using pixels.

The methods you are looking for are [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapCanvasProjection). `fromLatLngToContainerPixel` and `fromContainerPixelToLatLng` or `fromLatLngToDivPixel` and `fromDivPixelToLatLng`.

This means you should probably wrap up that code into an OverlayView and call `getProjection()` on your `map` to get the projection and then use one set of those methods to do the calculation.